# Is event bus library mechanism as bad as the use of static variables to pass data between activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, event-bus, otto

I'm learning Android, and AFAIK, the standard Android mechanism to pass data between Activities is using Intents which in turn are implemented as IPC on lower level (maybe I'm wrong).

It seems that recently have emerged a bunch of libraries to make life easier to Android devs. Between them, the famous Event Bus (Greenrobot's one, Square's Otto). I've been trying both (almost exact interface semantics) and have seen some posts around on how to use Greenrobot event bus to post events to an activity using .postSticky which allows to consume or pull the event on the new activity when this one is ready to fetch this data.

But from my understanding since now, the primary aim of using Intents (and therefore the tedious work of using serializable/parcelable objects when you deal with complex objects) is to allow Android to recreate this data after the system kills the app due to resources constraints, usually when you switch to another app and start playing around. So when in this situation, when you switch back to yor app, you get **NULL pointer** on the data that was passed using event bus.

Do I am missing something? Or simply this approach (event bus to pass data to activities), even very clean on code, is completely wrong?

Comment: + for what I could test, look that it is a reasonable approach to pass result to an activity instead of using startActivityForResult instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the primary aim of using Intents (and therefore the tedious work of using serializable/parcelable objects when you deal with complex objects) is to allow Android to recreate this data after the system kills the app due to resources constraints, usually when you switch to another app and start playing around

That is a feature of Android. I would not describe it as "the primary aim of using Intents". The primary aim of using `Intents` is to be able to invoke functionality (e.g., start an activity) without regards to whether that functionality executes in your current process, some separate process of yours, in some other running app's process, or in some process that does not yet exist (because the app in question is not running at the moment).

> So when in this situation, when you switch back to yor app, you get NULL pointer on the data that was passed using event bus.

No, you just do not get an event when you register your listener. So long as your code can handle that situation, there is no problem here.

> Or simply this approach (event bus to pass data to activities), even very clean on code, is completely wrong?

I would not recommend the approach. That being said, IMHO, it is not "completely wrong" either. "Completely wrong" would indicate that it is impossible to create a properly-functioning Android app using the technique. Android apps have a wide range of use cases, and so some might be able to survive using this technique even in isolation. And, using this technique in combination with other stuff (e.g., data persistence) may be perfectly fine in some cases.

`postSticky()` is simply an in-memory cache tied into an event bus. Caching is an important part of many Android apps, to minimize repetitious disk or network I/O. So long as `postSticky()` is only used as an in-memory cache, apps should not get into trouble. Apps that rely upon `postSticky()` surviving process termination *are* in trouble, though that is not unique to `postSticky()`, but rather is a general issue with in-memory caches. Apps that rely upon *any* sort of in-memory cache surviving process termination are in trouble.

Comment: > So long as your code can handle that situation, there is no problem here.

Could you clarify a little bit on this? What I'm trying to do is to pass a `List<ViewModel>` of complex objects (ViewModel) to an activity using `bus.postSticky(viewModels)` on the source activity and get that `List` to the destination activity to have a simple clean code and avoiding `Intents`and therefore serialization. But of course without falling in the trap of null pointer when "process is killed" by system. So when recreating dest Activity I can have the list again. Is that possible using the event bus?

Comment: @GerardB: You cannot avoid `Intents`, as then you have no activities at all, let alone ones communicating via an event bus. As I wrote, `postSticky()` is a cache. Use the cache if it is there, but be prepared to rebuild the objects if the cache is empty. Pass enough information in `Intent` extras to be able to rebuild the `List<ViewModel>` from the now-current data in your persistent store, in case the cached values are unavailable. All `startActivity()` calls involve IPC; do not pass `List<ViewModel>` around via `Intent` extras.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean "avoid Intents at all", I meant, avoid Intent's extras (to put `List<ViewModel>` inside). Of course I need an Intent to `startActivity()`. I will think on your tip and try to use sticky cache if available (most of time it will in my case) and try to build my `List<ViewModel>` in dest Activity passing some data to the Intent extra's if cache is not available (i.e. when recreating activity due to process killed). Thanks!