# Reference Fragment/AppCompatActivity from FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

**Question**
In a FragmentActivity, how can I access a reference to a Fragment or a AppCompatActivity?

**Scenario**
My application has tabs that allows to switch between fragments. Each tab has a button that transitions into a view accessed only from that tab (after the click).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
 private class (on)SectionPageAdapter extends FragmentPageAdataper{
  ...
  @Override public Fragment getItem(int position){
    ...
    F1 f1 = new F1();
    return f1;  
   }
 }
}

public class F1 extends Fragment{
...
 void onIntent(){
  ...
  Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), AccountTransition.class);
  this.startActivity(intent);
 }
}


public class F2 extends FragmentActivity{
 //how can i gain access to a reference from F1 class or MainActivity class?
}
```

[image]

Comment: after an intent has happened, I am inside the FragmentActivity. how can I access a reference to the class for the Fragment that launched the intent, or a reference to the class for the AppCompatActivity that is the top level Activity of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to get a reference to an `Activity`, this can cause memory leaks and can make code more fragile.

You should look into communication ways between `Activities` such as using a `BroadcastReceiver` or an `EventBus`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver

If you want something a bit simpler, I would recommend `EventBus`.
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Here is a quick example of how you could send data between two `Activities` without any references using `EventBus`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Subscribe()
    public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
        // Show the message.
    }
}
```

**F2.java**

```
public class F2 extends FragmentActivity{

    // Sending "Hello from F2" to anyone listening.
    public void sendMessage() {
        MessageEvent event = new MessageEvent("Hello from F2");
        EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: in reference to SO: [event-bus/static-var, practive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936993/is-event-bus-library-mechanism-as-bad-as-the-use-of-static-variables-to-pass-dat) is using BroadcastReceiver approach or EventBus approach the only way to obtain what I seek? *to reference MainActivity from F2 (after the intent has been executed by F1)?

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ I feel like that question is slightly different. They're trying to handle the lifecycle and using EventBus instead of Intents. That is not what I'm suggesting. You should use both. And I would strongly recommend not trying to get a reference to another `Activity`, as that's just going to cause issues and poor code. However, they do bring up `startActivityForResult` which could work if you're just trying to return a result from `F2`.